# Как задать минимальную и максимальную величины отступов от стенок контейнера?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qlayout, qvboxlayout

Мой код заполняет виджетами цветной контейнер `box`. В него попадают следующие элементы:

1. `picture` - некоторое изображение с закругленными краями. Я получаю его с помощью класса `Label`
2. Два виджета `QLabel` - `label1` и `label2`
3. Проста кнопка `btn`

Эти виджеты не выполняют прямых функций. Они нужны, чтобы можно было понять, как контейнер `box` располагает внутри себя элементы.

Окно приложения выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас меня не устраивает местоположение виджетов в `box`. Когда окно достигает достаточно больших размеров, элементы `picture` и `btn` находятся слишком близко к верхней и нижней границам контейнера соответственно.

Мне нужно как-то контролировать расстояние между элементами и границами, которые на схеме я назвал **`H1`** и **`H2`**:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я решил, что было бы здорово задать минимальную и максимальную величины отступов от стенок контейнера. Изначально величина этих оступов принимает минимальное значение, но, когда появляется больше места, она постепенно растет до максимального значения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, моя проблема решается другим способом, но я не могу придумать ничего лучше.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как навести порядок в контейнере?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(150, 150)
        self.setMinimumSize(150, 150)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            150, 150, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)

        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = 1

        main_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #7189DB;')
        container.setFixedWidth(250)
        container.setMinimumHeight(150)
        main_box.addWidget(container)
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container) # КОНТЕЙНЕР 'BOX'

        picture = Label('picture1')
        box.addWidget(picture, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 1')
        box.addWidget(label1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 2')
        box.addWidget(label2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        box.addWidget(btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, какие действия вы выполняете? Покажите изображение что вы получаете и покажите что вы хотите получит?

Comment: Хорошо. На рисование картинки у меня уйдет некоторое время. Я сообщу, когда обновлю вопрос

Comment: @S.Nick, я переформулировал свой вопрос. Не знаю, стал ли он теперь понятнее. Мне очень тяжело дается понимание того, как будут располагаться виджеты в контейнерах при масштабировании, поэтому, я могу говорить какие-нибудь странные вещи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант

> QBoxLayout::addStretch(int stretch = 0)
>
> Добавляет растягиваемое пространство (QSpacerItem) с нулевым минимальным размером и коэффициентом растяжения растягивания до конца этого макета блока.

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtMultimedia

class Label(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Label, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setMaximumSize(150, 150)
        self.setMinimumSize(150, 150)
        self.radius = 10 

        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)

        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            150, 150, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)

        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)

        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.index = 1

        main_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #7189DB;')
        container.setFixedWidth(250)
#        container.setMinimumHeight(150)
        container.setMinimumHeight(282)                                # +++
        
        main_box.addWidget(container)
        
        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container) # КОНТЕЙНЕР 'BOX'

        picture = Label('im.png')
        box.addStretch(1)                                              # +++
        box.addWidget(picture, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 1')
        box.addStretch(1)                                              # +++
        box.addWidget(label1, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Text 2')
        box.addStretch(1)                                              # +++
        box.addWidget(label2, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        box.addStretch(1)                                              # +++
        box.addWidget(btn, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        box.addStretch(1)                                              # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Большое спасибо! Я знал метод `addStretch()`, но почему-то забыл о нем в нужный момент :)

Comment: @MAXIM045 Бывает. Ничего страшного, скоро все станет на свои места :)